# Ok to paint Kilz on wooding flooring with faced insulation beneath?

Tags: flooring

My livingroom carpeted floor has some pet odors and cigarette smoke smell from a previous tenant. I'm replacing the flooring with laminate and the installer recommended painting [Kilz](http://www.kilz.com/products/primer/kilz-2) on the floor prior to installing the new flooring to seal in the smells. He said that the laminate and underlayment might be enough, but to be sure I should go with the Kilz.

This is the ground floor with wooden flooring above a crawl space -- the floor is insulated from the bottom with faced insulation with the vapor barrier on the insulation bats facing the floor.

Will the addition of Kilz (and the new laminate flooring) on the floor cause vapor problems since we'll have 2 vapor barriers facing the floor -- the Kilz on top and the insulation below.

Or is Kilz not a true vapor barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the batts have a paper facing, that's not actually a vapor barrier, it's vapor *retarder*, and you'll be fine.

If instead, the facer is plastic or aluminum, or there's a sheet of polyethylene sealing the floor, then yes those would be vapor barriers and you would have a problem. Solution: remove the vapor barrier.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I  didn't realize there were differences in insulation vapor barrier, but I looked around at some [insulation data sheets](http://www.jm.com/content/dam/jm/global/en/building-insulation/Files/BI%20Data%20Sheets/Resi%20and%20Commercial/BID-0144_BioBinder_DS.pdf), and they do show a much higher water vapor transmission for the kraft paper faced -- the paper faced is 1 PERM, foil faced is .05 PERM.